# Traducción en español para "Fixer upper"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Un [*fixer upper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixer-upper) es una casa (o apartamento o propiedad similar) que necesita reformas (aunque posiblemente se pueda vivir en ella) pero que tras las obras puede incrementar el valor de la propiedad por encima de lo invertido.

Así puesto suena un poco de perogrullo, pero básicamente es como si comprases la casa más fea del barrio, que está a mitad de precio por estar muy vieja y necesitar las reformas. Gastas, supongamos, 50.000 unidades de moneda (cuando todas las otras casas del barrio cuestan el doble) y gastas en reformas pongamos otras 30.000 unidades de moneda. Al final has gastado unos 80.000 (y has pasado por el calvario de las reformas, que no es poco) para comprar y acondicionar tu casa, pero como ahora es similar a las otras del barrio puedes suponer que tienes cierto beneficio sobre la inversión o que como poco has incrementado el valor de tu patrimonio, al tener una propiedad que ya no vale el precio original, sino un precio de mercado mucho mayor (vamos, que posiblemente no valga simplemente 50.000 + 30.000, sino algo parecido a las otras casas del barrio, que puede ser mayor, por lo que sales ganando).

No estoy seguro de si hay un término ya aceptado en español. Hay un montón de programas de televisión de "redecora tu casa" y similar, ya sean versiones de programas de países angloparlantes (que usarán el término *fixer upper*) o producciones patrias (que usarán algún otro término o expresión).

¿Qué término se usa en español para *fixer upper*?

Comment: *Casa **a reformar*** es como lo he dicho yo, y es breve (y solo una sílaba más del inglés, aunque con una pronunciación probablemente algo más corta). Y ojo: *Fixer upper* en inglés puede también referir a otras cosas como vehículos.

Comment: Puede haber una frase o palabra que signifique lo mismo, pero para la práctica (que se entienda sin necesidad de preguntar) deberías usar casa *a reparar*, *a reformar*, *a renovar*, *a remodelar*, o algún otro similar.

Comment: Tengo una idea pero quiero ver cómo quieres usar el término.  En ELU se requiere una frase con ______ donde va el término buscado.  ¿Aquí no?

Comment: Se usa incluso con personas: _So he's a bit of a fixer-upper, but this we're certain of: you can fix this fixer-upper up with a little bit of love!_ (Por favor, ¿quién a estas alturas no ha visto _Frozen_? :-D

Comment: @guifa, "casa a reformar" me parece perfecta. Lo que no sé es si se pierden algunas connotaciones y por eso quería ver qué me explica la comunidad Spanish.SE. Es evidente que al meter el dinero de las reformas incrementas el valor de la propiedad (sea la que sea). Siempre entendí (puedo estar equivocado) que la connotación de _fixer upper_ era la de "oportunidad" y que el valor final puede ser mayor a lo invertido económicamente. Una casa puede necesitar reformas para no derrumbarse (mantenimiento) o puedes reformar como inversión, y esa connotación es lo que no sé bien cómo traducir.

Answer (score 2):

Qué me vas a contar, si mi mujer estuvo un tiempo enganchada a todos esos programas de reformas de casas. A uno de ellos le pusieron de nombre ***Reformar para vender***, creo, que podría ser una posible opción para lo que buscas. Lo malo es que ese término está muy enfocado a las viviendas, mientras que *fixer upper* se puede referir a cualquier cosa, ya sean objetos o personas. Por lo que yo te propongo esta opción, que tiene un sentido muy similar al que buscas y que también se puede aplicar a cualquier cosa o persona:

> [**diamante bruto**, o **diamante en bruto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DezzXII#1T3iMc5)
>
> 1. m. Persona o cosa de valor o potencial grandes, pero sin desarrollar o aprovechar.

Aunque es cierto que tradicionalmente se ha usado esta expresión con las personas, como ves la propia definición extiende su uso a cualquier cosa, por lo que podrías decir "esa casa parece la peor del barrio, pero es un diamante en bruto". De hecho, solo con decir que algo o alguien es un diamante en bruto, ya estás diciendo sutilmente que ahora mismo no destaca por su excelencia precisamente.

Un ejemplo sacado del CREA que pone de manifiesto dicha sutileza:

> *Y lo intentó, en efecto, puesto que de regreso a la granja, Doña Mariana puso todo su empeño en la ardua tarea de transformar el asombroso diamante en bruto que era en aquellos momentos la princesa, en una exquisita dama capaz de brillar en los más sofisticados salones de las cortes europeas.*
>
> Alberto Vázquez-Figueroa, "Caribes (Cienfuegos 2)", 1988 (España).

Personajes típicos de películas Disney (ya que me has recordado *Frozen* con lo del *fixer upper*) que son considerados como "diamantes en bruto" son Kristoff, de la misma *Frozen*, o Aladdin, de la película que lleva su nombre.

Otro ejemplo que no hace referencia a una persona concreta:

> *La riqueza no se dibuja, Felipe, la riqueza se crea, pero no llevando a la ruina a los más débiles... España es como un diamante en bruto, y nosotros sus tallistas, pero mi padre se ha propuesto ser el carnero de las churras y las merinas.*
>
> Manuel Martínez Mediero, "Juana del amor hermoso", 1982 (España).

Y para que veas que la expresión no entiende ni de épocas ni de regiones:

> *De los cuales baños se puede creer que se irán descubriendo otros que vernán a ser célebres en el mundo, si Dios concede a los nuestros buenos sucesos, con los cuales no hay duda de que tratándose aquella inculta tierra, verná a ser toda ella lo que después de labrado un diamante bruto cuya apariencia prometa inestimable valor [...].*
>
> Alonso González Nájera, "Desengaño y reparo de la guerra del reino de Chile", 1614 (Chile).

Comment: No es mala respuesta (+1), pero en inglés también existe la expresión ["diamond in the rough"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diamond_in_the_rough). Curiosamene según ese enlace la expresión se usa solo para personas... Supongo que "reformar para vender" es el programa "fixer upper". La connotación sería "y si no es para vender?" tal vez "Reformar para incrementar valor"? que en el fondo es un poco obvio.

Comment: +1 diamante en bruto lo he oído usarse en ese sentido exactamente y resulta muy elegante

Answer (score 0):

Ganga es un equivalente. No se puede representar todo un contexto social en una traducción, solo aproximadamente